# CakePHP w/ jQuery (Javascript/Ajax) simple link and update - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am simply trying to use jQuery to print out the contents of an action. But I cannot get my div to update with the echoed content. What am I doing wrong?

**birds_controller.php**

```
...
    var $helpers = array('Js', 'Html', 'Ajax');
    var $components = array('RequestHandler');

function birds_ajax_1() {
    function birds_ajax_1_func_1() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo "Text from Ajax clickaroo.";
    }
}
...
```

**birds_ajax_1.ctp**

```
<?php
    echo $ajax->link('Ajax Link', array('controller' => 'birds',
    'action' => 'birds_ajax_1_func_1'), 
         array('update' => 'ajax_div', 'complete' => 'alert("Ok.")'));
?>

<div id="ajax_div"></div> <!-- echoed text is not showing here? -->
```

**default.ctp**

```
...
echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); // Yes. My jQuery is being pulled in OK.
...

...
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
...
```

**This is what is being dumped to my source:**

```
...
        <a href="/php/cake_app_birds_v1.3/birds/birds_ajax_1_func_1"     id="link2019467549" onclick=" event.returnValue = false; return false;">link1</a><script     type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
Event.observe('link2019467549', 'click', function(event) { new Ajax.Updater('ajax_div','/php/cake_app_birds_v1.3/birds/birds_ajax_1_func_1',     {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request, json) {alert("Ok.")},     requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'ajax_div']}) }, false);
//]]>
```

Comment: I don't think `birds_ajax_1_func_1()` is getting called.  Try putting it directly under controller. CakePHP is looking for a function of birds_controller, but this function is a function of one of those functions.

Comment: Are you using cake 1.3 or 1.2?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I actually just solved the problem with a bit of ask-the-teacher-and-realize-the-answer-syndrome!. To answer these questions, I am using 1.3. The main problem was several fold. I am going to post my working solution as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**birds_controller.php**

```
var $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Html', 'Ajax');
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

function birds_ajax_1() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    $this->render('/elements/birds_ajax_1'); // this birds_ajax_1.ctp contains the output into the #ajax_div.
    }
}
```

**birds_ajax_1.ctp**

```
<?php
// Note I am not using the $ajax->link(...
echo $this->Js->link('Ajax Link', array('controller' => 'birds',
'action'     => 'birds_ajax_1'), array('update' => '#ajax_div'));

?>

<div id="ajax_div"></div>
```

Nothing changed in default.ctp.

Hope this is helpful to someone else who might be going through the confusion I just went through! Glad I found the light! Now onto some jQuery sorting ? Oh boy.